# Using fingerprint lock, forgot password, phone is locked and already at 60 minutes

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, locked-out

I have Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge with a fingerprint lock and password as the backup. I forgot the password for backup and there is no way of getting on my phone. When I use fingerprint, it asks for the password when nothing is wrong with my fingerprint. It doesn't show a forgotten password to click when I have many failed attempts. Already at 60 minutes and it keeps getting higher.

I have already tried Android Device Manager and found my mobile and Dr. Fone which I have to enable USB debugging, but I can't do it because the phone is locked. I use Android Device Manager, it says it won't set a new password because one is already set.

I don't want to factory reset because I don't have it backed up since about 3 weeks and it doesn't back up everything, it only backs up like messages and other unnecessary things I think.

I really don't understand why it asks for a password when my fingerprint is absolutely fine. Is there any way to unlock the device?

Comment: Have you tried the Android Debug Method detailed here: [Android Debug Method Explained by MakeUseOf](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-you-can-return-someones-lost-phone-by-thinking-like-a-thief/). Came across this article when I needed to unlock a lost phone.

Answer (score 2):

This is a security feature of Android: it will occasionally ask for the password after being unlocked with a fingerprint (presumably in case someone steals your phone and cuts your finger off, or I don’t know why). That’s just how it works. Fingerprint is only a convenience, you really have to remember the password.

[According to Google](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3388218?hl=en), your only option is to hard reset the phone and start it all over.

I would not be so worried about backups: nowadays most of your data is stored in the cloud. I don’t know about your situation specifically, but the only pieces of information that are not in the cloud on *my* phone are SMS and call history, which I don’t care about. Therefore, I would not hesitate to erase my phone.

---

Fine print: in case your disk is not encrypted and the bootloader is unlocked, it is pretty easy to extract all the information, but I assume, if you had bootloader unlocked, you would not be asking your question here.